# Prove that if $V=\text{constant}$ then the second part in the paratheses after the integral sign is equal to $0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, tensors, applications

$$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt^i} \underset{\large V(t)}{\iiint} \Psi \,\mathrm dV= \underset{\large V(t)}{\iiint} \left({\frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}+\nabla\cdot\Psi\mathbf v_i}\right)\, \mathrm dV$$

The expression shown above is a condition.

Prove that if $V=\text{constant}$ then the second part in the parentheses after the integral sign is equal to $0$.

[image]

[image]

The book says the equation within the expression is a form of Reynold's transport theorem

You can pretty much ignore the $i$ there.

reference: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ReynoldsTransportTheorem.html

Comment: I don't understand your notation $\dfrac{d}{dt^i}$. what does that mean?

Comment: @MPW The author didn't indicated it originally anywhere, but it is a math identity coming from an engineering book and indicated that it is citing from Vectors, Tensors and the Basic Equations of Fluid Mechanics, so I may also had to ask "what was that" to the community here